# How do I add a new element to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to add a new element to my array of objects. Each array element `list[x]` for an arbitrary integer `x` is an object of the form:

```
{
    name: "insert-name",
    value: "insert-value"
}
```

I was told that for adding an element to an array, I must use the `push()` function. So that is what I did:

```
exports.handle = function(input) {
for(var i=0; i<cc.list.length; i++) {
    if(input == cc.list[i].name) {
        return cc.list[i].value;
    }
}

if(input.startsWith("create-cc")) {
    var namevalue = input.slice(10, input.length);
    var spaceloc = namevalue.indexOf(" ");
    var nname = namevalue.slice(0, spaceloc);
    var nvalue = namevalue.slice(spaceloc+1, namevalue.length);

    cc.list.push({
        name: nname,
        value: nvalue
    });

    return "Command successfully created! Typing `Z!" + name +"` will output `" + value +"` now!" ;
}

return "Error.";
```

};

`cc.list` is the name of the array in this module `.js` file. I use the inputs from a user to be filled as the name and value for the new array element that I want to add to the list. However I got an error on the console, which told me:

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

This totally makes sense, since I did not declare such a parameter. But doesn't that parameter already exist as a part of the "template" object that forms the array element? Why does this method not work? And how do I make a new array object element to be appended to this array?

Comment: `name is not defined` nname => name

Comment: @WalterChapilliquen-wZVanG Can you elaborate please? I dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: The error specifically is referring to the use of the variable ```name``` in your return statement, which does not exist in any scope.

Comment: At what line do you get the error? I would assume that it comes from the `return`-statement and not the object creating. When returning you are referencing `name` and `value`, instead of the object parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
return "Command successfully created! Typing `Z!" + name +"` will output `" + value +"` now!" ;
```

It is making use of a variable named `name`, however no such variable exists, hence the error `ReferenceError: name is not defined`

You have made the same error with `value`, there is no variable defined with that name.

You do however have variables named `nname` and `nvalue`, so perhaps this is what you were intending to write:

```
return "Command successfully created! Typing `Z!" + nname +"` will output `" + nvalue +"` now!" ;
```